# How to I achieve this look

Tags: color, style-identification, inspiration

How can I acheive this look of the colors on the pineapple? I have a series of photos that I'm wanting to apply a style like this to. Any help or ideas are much appreciated [image]

Comment: Please share what you have tried and where you feel you are struggling.

Answer (score 2):

It would really depend on the starting image.  Different images and lighting would require different approaches.

However in general, the way I'd go about it in Photoshop is to use a reduced opacity gradient map adjustment layer, with a gradient of blue, green, and pink. And then add tweaks using a hue/saturation adjustment layer.

[image]

This is the custom gradient I used

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @Billy Kerr I followed your suggestion and I'm so happy with the results I got. I've been  trying it on a few of my images and they're looking great. I can't thank you enough for taking the time to help me out, much appreciated